# my code ends with OverflowError when I have large inputs

Tags: python, trigonometry

One of my homework questions, and I am only allowed to import pi.

The question asks to compute the cosine function by Taylor series, which I have done so far.  The outputs I get are correct however when k gets larger than 90, I get OverflowError: int too large to convert to float.

```
from math import pi

def myCos(angle,k):
    total=0
    for i in range(k):
        total += (((-1)**(i))*((angle*pi/180)**(2*(i))))/(fact(2*(i)))
    return total

def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return fact(n-1)*n
```

In order to get full marks for this question, the code has to accept k > 100.

i.e

```
myCos(45,5)
0.7071068056832942

myCos(45,60)
0.7071067811865475

myCos(45,90)
total += (((-1)**(i))*((angle*pi/180)**(2*(i))))/(fact(2*(i)))
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

Can someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: I would suggest using `math.log`, but it seems you aren't allowed to import that :/ . If the overflow error is from factorial, continuously divide by each number (1,2,3,4...,n) instead of calculating the factorial all at once

Comment: `for i in range(max(k, 86)):`?

Comment: I'd also memoize the previously computed results of the factorial using a dict. That's certainly going to really improve the run time when you need to calculate many terms of the Taylor series like it seems you're required to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main division in the summation exceeded the range of type `float`.  To do that division, you have to convert the denominator to type `float`.  `fact(2*85)` is larger than the maximum `float` value.

Do the operations in a difference order.  For instance:

```
numer = (angle*pi/180)**(2*(i))
for denom in range(1, 2*i + 1):
    numer /= denom
```

Now `numer` is a reasonable (?) representation of the value desired.  If you need better reliability, "chunk" the denominator values and divide by the product of, say, groups of 10 `denom` values.

```
def myCos(angle,k):
    total=0
    for i in range(k):
        numer = (angle*pi/180)**(2*(i))
        for denom in range(2, 2*i+1):
            numer /= denom
        total += (-1) ** i * numer
    return total

print(myCos(45,5))
print(myCos(45,60))
print(myCos(45,90))
```

Output:

```
0.7071068056832942
0.7071067811865475
0.7071067811865475
```

Comment: Let me know if I understand your code correctly,

Instead of dividing the entire numer by the result of factorial, your code divides the numer from individual numbers that make up that factorial number.
...
ie. numer / 1, numer / 2, numer / 3... instead of numer / (one big factorial integer)
...
Can I also say that the limit of K is brought up further with your code but may still fail if the K value is extremely large ?

Comment: You understand correctly.  Many times, overflow of intermediate results is alleviated by reordering the operations -- which is just what I've done.  Yes, it can still fail, if `k` reaches 170! -- which is notably larger than 85.

Comment: Another thing to note is that if `k` *were* to reach 170!, then the computational result of those terms would have long converged to 0, no longer contributing to the cumulative sum.  If you require that level of accuracy in your results, you'll need to use a different data type and start your accumulation from the "small" end.  You can look up numerical methods for retaining diminutive results in such a long computation.